# If there is one what is the Atom Editor keyboard shortcut to insert a new line after the current one whilst mid-line?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

I am trying to find the shortcut to start a new line once i have finished typing the current one whilst there are still words/characters/intergers etc after where the cursor is, i.e. print('hello world') auto adds the ') after world and i want to move to a new line without moving ') down.
In Sublime you can press ctrl-Enter, and from what i have read on another post you should be able to do the same, however when i try nothing happens. Is this supposed to work by default or is it something i have to add to Atom by myself?

Any help that you can provide will be greatly appreciated.